# The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, shipping-methods

After select shipping method go to payments choose payments then click on My billing and shipping address are the same then click on place order button getting below error in Magento 2.4.4-p2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message "The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again" typically appears when a customer is trying to check out on a Magento 2 store, but has not selected a shipping method. This can happen when there is an issue with the shipping methods that are available to the customer, or if there is a problem with the shipping method selection process.

Here are a few things that can cause this error message, and how to fix them:

```
1. Misconfigured shipping methods: Make sure that your shipping methods are correctly configured in the Magento admin panel. Go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods and verify that the methods are enabled and configured correctly.

2. Shipping method not available for the customer's shipping address: Ensure that the shipping methods that you have enabled are available for the customer's shipping address.

3. Shipping method not available for the customer's cart weight or dimensions: If you have weight or dimension based shipping methods enabled, make sure that the customer's cart meets the weight or dimension requirements for the method they want to use.

4. Shipping method not available for the customer's shipping address country: Ensure that the customer is able to select shipping method for their country or region.

5. Custom shipping method not correctly implemented: if you have a custom shipping method that is implemented then you need to ensure that the method is correctly implemented, and shipping method is available for the customer.

6. Shipping Method is not visible to the customer: If you have a custom shipping method that is not visible to the customer, then ensure that the shipping method is visible.

7. JavaScript issue: Sometimes it may be an issue with javascript, which is used for shipping method. Check the browser console for any javascript error related to shipping method.

8. Check if you have any custom rule or condition which is causing the shipping method to hide.
```

By addressing these points and debugging the exact cause, you can resolve this issue of "The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again" and allow the customers to check out successfully.